# Why onCreate() function is not call by the constructor

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm a newbie in java and android studio. I'm trying to code a to do list application. To achieve this, I need to store user's task in a database base. For this I follow this tutorial:

[https://www.sitepoint.com/starting-android-development-creating-todo-app/][1]

And more precisely the following code for create the database:

```
package com.aziflaj.todolist.db;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class TaskDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public TaskDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, TaskContract.DB_NAME, null, TaskContract.DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
                TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

I modified it like

```
package com.example.steven.myapplication;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHandler";
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "taskRegister";
    private static final String TASK_TABLE= "task";
    private static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    private static final String COLUMN_TASK = "task";
    private static final String COLUMN_STATE = "false";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, "taskRegister", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String database_table = "CREATE TABLE task (" +
                "id int INTEGER PRIMARY " +
                "task TEXT" +
                "state TEXT )";
        db.execSQL(database_table);
        Log.d(TAG, "===Inside onCreate from DatabaseHandler===");
    }
```

I voluntarily remove any line in order to avoid you to have to read too many code. :)

Does anyone can help to understand why the onCreate() function isn't call by the constructor in order to initialize my database ?

I call my constructor from another class like:

```
DatabaseHandler test = new DatabaseHandler(get.Application());
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call `test.getWritableDatabase()` otherwise the `onCreate()` callback won't be executed.

> SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase ()
>
> Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and
> writing. The first time this is called, the database will be opened
> and onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int)
> and/or onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) will be called.

For more info:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()

Comment: Thank you very much ! I didn't see this function because I was looking why the onCreate() function wasn't call in the official android studio documentation but I didn't think about that another function could call explicitly onCreate() function. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Lino answer,

In general you will not find lifecycle hooks like `onCreate` being used from the constructor.
This is related to basic OOPS concepts.

The basic purpose of a constructor is to *simply initialize* the object and nothing more. If a lifecycle or some callback method is dependant on a constructor and it fails, the object initialisation itself will fail.

Separating it from the initialisation logic will allow to handle the lifecycle errors separately and it wont affect object initialisation.

Answer (score 0):

You must use `getWritableDatabase()` in your DatabaseHelper class.

From the [Android `getWritableDatabase` tutorial](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#getWritableDatabase()):

> Once opened successfully, the database is cached, so you can call this method every time you need to write to the database. (Make sure to call close() when you no longer need the database.) Errors such as bad permissions or a full disk may cause this method to fail, but future attempts may succeed if the problem is fixed.